# Why is my font turning into unknown symbols in some areas of my desktop UI?

Tags: gnome, fonts

If effects my desktop icons, as well as all text in Nautilus, and other programs, like Sublime Merge in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This reflects a problem with the font cache (for your user). You can refresh the font cache with the following commands in a terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig
fc-cache -r -v
```